# ¿Cómo se puede evitar que se ejecute un INSERT a tabla utilizando condiciones?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una duda sobre la opción `Alter Table` de una base de datos `MySql`. He creado una tabla de libros:

```
CREATE TABLE Libro(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre VARCHAR(100),
    id_Tipo INT NOT NULL,
    Activo ENUM('0','1'),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_Tipo) REFERENCES TipoLibro (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

En esta tabla quiero crear una constraint que no me permita insertar dos libros con el mismo Nombre y el mismo id_tipo cuando `Activo='1'` . Cuando `Activo='0'` sí tiene que permitirme la inserción.

A continuación muestro el código que tengo del alter table correspondiente:

```
ALTER TABLE Libro ADD CONSTRAINT NombreTipo UNIQUE (Nombre,id_Tipo);
```

Espero que me podáis ayudar y me indiquéis alguna forma de crear una Constraint en la base de datos que no me permita hacer lo indicado arriba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `UNIQUE KEY` no servirá en este caso porque entonces solo podrías tener 2 filas en tu tabla para 1 valor de `Nombre`. En tu caso, si quieres controlar esto a nivel de base de datos, te convendría utilizar un trigger. Aquí un ejemplo:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER lol_insert BEFORE INSERT ON lol
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Libro WHERE Nombre = NEW.NOMBRE AND Activo = 1) THEN
        signal SQLSTATE '45000'; -- esto lanza el error
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```